Обработка словаря с НЕ уникальными ключами
Есть словарь с не уникальными ключами:
_dict = {
"key": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
},
"key":  {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4    
}
}

Могу ли я как-то проитерироваться по каждой паре ключ : значение?
Знаю что если бы ключи были уникальные, то мог бы просто пройтись циклом
for key in _dict:
    pass

Но в данном случае такой способ не сработает насколько я понял...
PS: Сам словарь берётся с .txt файла, так что поменять принцип формирования самого словаря я не могу.

print(_dict) -> {'key': {'x': 3, 'y': 4}} -> ответ: нельзя.

не бывает словарей с неуникальными ключами одного порядка.

В txt файле именно так выглядит как вы показали?

@strawdog Понял, просто считав данные с txt  файла и прописав type(data)питон выдал что это dict. Но видать сам принцип работы со словарями не предусматривает таких ситуаций. Видать придётся обрабатывать данные не как словарь. В любом случае спасибо

@insolor  Да, там просто текст формата {"key": {"x": 1,"y": 2},"key":  {"x": 3,"y": 4 }}
Только вместо key / x / y другие слова.

Вот там прямо _dict = ... написано или всё там JSON который вы как-то читаете?

У стандартного парсера JSON есть параметр object_pairs_hook с помощью которого можно достать информацию из дублирующихся ключей.

@AlexeyTen Да, Вы правы, это JSON. Что-то я решил это словарём назвать.  Глянул про "object_pairs_hook",выглядит как решение моей проблемы. Сейчас пойду подробнее читать. Спасибо.

@Nashlow Да, Вы правы, это JSON. - мне не понятно как создавался файл (производился dump)? Эта структура возможна только в виде списка словарей.
